# How to use Python Regular expression to get the character in the middle of the forward slash

Tags: python

I have this string: `https://app.redretarget.com/sapp/ptag/jxy666.myshopify.com`.

How do I use Python Regular expression to get the character in the middle of the forward slash?

I want to Get: `['app.redretarget.com','sapp','ptag','jxy666.myshopify.com']`

When I use:

```
cmd = 'https://app.redretarget.com/sapp/ptag/jxy666.myshopify.com'
pin_url = re.compile(r'/(.*?)/{0,1}')
print pin_url.findall(cmd)
```

I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` by "/". I am using `filter` to remove empty elements in the list.

```
string ='https://app.redretarget.com/sapp/ptag/jxy666.myshopify.com'
print filter(None, string.split("/"))
```

**Output:**

```
['https:', 'app.redretarget.com', 'sapp', 'ptag', 'jxy666.myshopify.com']
```

Comment: Is it me?  Or does this not match OP's desired output?

Comment: Also, using `filter` with `None` seems a clumsy way to handle the `//`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of regex you could use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse) and [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib%20path#basic-use):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path

cmd = 'https://app.redretarget.com/sapp/ptag/jxy666.myshopify.com'
parsed = urlparse(cmd)
parts = (parsed.netloc, ) + Path(parsed.path).parts[1:]
print(parts)  # ('app.redretarget.com', 'sapp', 'ptag', 'jxy666.myshopify.com')
```

note that `urlparse` could also parse more complex urls; the result of `urlparse` in your case is

```
print(parsed)
# ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='app.redretarget.com', 
#             path='/sapp/ptag/jxy666.myshopify.com', params='', query='',
#             fragment='')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose splitting twice

```
cmd.split('//', 1)[1].split('/')

['app.redretarget.com', 'sapp', 'ptag', 'jxy666.myshopify.com']
```